Error al realizar seeds en laravel 10
llevo un rato dándole vueltas a ver si consigo hacer una migración fresca con seeders y no consigo que me haga el seedeo, la migración si la hace perfectamente, no pretendo usar factory alguna, el comando que uso es:
"./vendor/bin/sail artisan migrate:fresh --seed"
Tengo dos seeds que deseo realizar, dejo sus codigos:
juegosMesa:
<?php

   namespace Database\Seeders;

   use Illuminate\Database\Console\Seeds\WithoutModelEvents;
   use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
   use App\Models\Juego;

   class JuegosTableSeeder extends Seeder{
    public function run(): void    {
        $juego1=new Juego;
        $juego1->codigo="00000001";
        $juego1->nombre="Hive";
        $juego1->activo= true;
        $juego1->jugadroes_minimos="2";
        $juego1->jugadores_maximos="2";
        $juego1->descripcion="Juego similar al ajedrez cuyo objetivo es reodear la reina    del oponente.";
        $juego1->save();
   }

El databaseSEeder esta asi:
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;


class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder{
    public function run(): void{
        $this->call(JuegosTableSeeder::class);
        $this->call(JugadoresTableSeeder::class);
    }
}

Los modelos los hice en relación a las migraciones son:
El de Juego:
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;

class Juego extends Model{
    use Listable;

    protected $table = 'jeugos';
    protected $fillable = ['id', 'codigo', 'nombre', 'activo', 'jugadores_minimos', 'jugadores_maximos', 'descripcion'];
    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $incrementing = true;
    protected $appends = ['',];

    public function jugador(){
        return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Jugador::class,'id', 'jugador_id');
    }
    public function getJugadorNombreAttribute(){
        if($this->jugador()->first()){
            return $this->jugador()->first()->nombre;
        }else{
            return "";
       }
    }
    public function puntuacion(){
        return $this->hasMany(App\Models\Puntuacion::class,'id', 'puntuacion_id');

    }

    public static function campos(){
        return[
            new ItemListado('codigo', 'juegos.codigo', Lang::get('site.codigo')),
            new ItemListado('nombre', 'juegos.nombre', Lang::get('site.nombre')),
            new ItemListado('activo', 'juegos.activo', Lang::get('site.activo')),
            new ItemListado('jugadores_minimos', 'juegos.juegadores_minimos', Lang::get('site.jugadores_minimos')),
            new ItemListado('jugadores_maximos', 'juegos.jugadores_maximos', Lang::get('site.jugadores_maximos')),
            new ItemListado('descripcion', 'juegos.descripcion', Lang::get('site.descripcion')),
        ];
    }
    public static function campos_defecto(){
        return ['codigo', 'nombre', 'activo', 'jugadores_minimos', 'jugadores_maximos', 'descripcion'];
    }
}

Y el de Jugador es similar.
Ahora tras solucionar eso, me da otro error con el mismo comando, aun sigo intentando seedear las 2 tablas, esto es lo que me da:


Ahí dice que JuegosTableSeeder no existe. Tu clase se llama JuegosTableSeeders, con una S final. Luego tienes errores tipograficos en jugadores_minimos, está mal escrito jugadores.

Vale.....tras un error inesperado(no suelo apagar el ordenador, suelo dejarlo suspendido", se ha ido la luz esta mañana y, como es obvio, cata pluf.....
se me ha hecho un "rollback" de una de las seeds, ya esta corregido, y arreglado los fallos, ahora me queda añadir los middleware y helpers

Alex, si se ha generado un nuevo error, por favor crea una nueva publicación. Los problemas son particulares, y las respuestas igual. Y recuerda, código y errores, en TEXTO.

Ok,, como es parte de lo mismo, al migrar, pensé que iba aquí, si he de hacer otra publicación, la hago.

¿puedes mostrar tu modelo Jugador y mas detalles del error?
Intenta de esta forma tu seeder, asi utilizas el metodo create para tu modelo Jugador:
class JugadoresTableSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     */
    public function run(): void
    {
        Jugador::create([
            'numero_jugador' => 1,
            'nombre' => 'Invitado1',
            'puntos' => 0,
            'activo' => true,
           //Esto en caso de que tengas timestamps en tu tabla
            'created_at' => '2023-10-11 19:33:13', 
            'updated_at' => '2023-10-11 19:33:26'
       ]);
    }
}

Es importante que revises los tipos de dato que intentas insertar, asi como tu modelo, es decir validar que todos los campos coincidan:
Algo asi:
 protected $fillable = [
        'numero_jugador',
        'nombre',
        'puntos',
        'activo'
    ];


la tabla jeugos no existe, en la consola te lo dice, borra del modelo protected $table = 'jeugos'; o ponle bien el nombre de la tabla a la propiedad
